# Angular component processes input change that originated from itself

Tags: angular, rxjs

Using Angular 4 with TypeScript, RxJS and the Reactive Forms module.

Please consider the following code:

```
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, EventEmitter, Input, NgModule, Output, SimpleChanges, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {BehaviorSubject,Subscription} from 'rxjs/Rx';

interface Question {
  id: string;
  label: string;
}

interface State {
  question: Question;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>App</h2>
      <edit-question [question]="question$ | async" (questionChange)="questionChanged($event)"></edit-question>
      <edit-question [question]="question$ | async" (questionChange)="questionChanged($event)"></edit-question>
    </div>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class App {
  state$ = new BehaviorSubject<State>({
    question: {id: 'q1', label: 'Question1'}
  });
  question$ = this.state$.map(s => s.question);

  questionChanged(q: Question): void {
    console.log('App.questionChanged', q);
    this.state$.next({question: q});
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'edit-question',
  template: `
    <div [formGroup]="form">
      <h3>Question</h3>
      <div>ID: {{question.id}}</div>
      <div>Label: <input type="text" formControlName="label"></div>
    </div>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class EditQuestionComponent implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {
  @Input() question: Question;
  @Output() questionChange = new EventEmitter<Question>();

  form: FormGroup;
  formChangesSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({id: '', label: ''});
    this.formChangesSubscription = this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      console.log('EditQuestionComponent.valueChange', value);
      let updated = {id: value.id, label: value.label};

      console.log('EditQuestionComponent.questionChange.emit', updated);
      this.questionChange.emit(updated);
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log('EditQuestionComponent.ngOnChanges', changes);
    this.form.reset({id: this.question.id, label: this.question.label}, {emitEvent: false});
  } 

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.formChangesSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App, EditQuestionComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Also available as a Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/F3uv5i1M63ADrFId0lif?p=preview).

Here we have:

- A parent component and two instances of the same child component (on purpose)
- All components are using OnPush change detection strategy
- Parent maintains state using a BehaviorSubject
- Parent sends state down to child component using an async pipe
- Parent registers to state changes from child component and produces a new state based on given change

When running the Plunker, focusing at the begining of the 1st text input (before Question1) and typing a letter, the caret jumps to the end of the input.

From what I understand, this is to be expected:

- Form control value changes, so form value changes
- Form valueChanges subscription kicks in and emits a new question
- Parent event handler receives the new question and produces a new state
- New state value is produced, then mapped to a new question value, and new question value is pushed down to child component
- Child component detects new question value through ngOnChanges and patches form value, thereby pushing to the end of the input

So while this makes sense, I'm wondering how to avoid this. The child component could set a `ignoreNextChange` flag before emitting the change and test + reset it in `ngOnChanges` to make sure It ignore changes it itself initiated, but this feels like a kludge.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The plnkr works fine for me .I edit text and cursor stays there and both the inputs are in sync

Comment: you can check if your formcontrol (the one that causes the change) is dirty or not. if not, change came from outside, if yes, change came from itself. there is a method formgroup.controls['yourFormControl'].dirty

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the selection state. this is a dirty way:

```
 // get reference to input element
  @ViewChild('inEl') inEl;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    let start = this.inEl.nativeElement.selectionStart;
    let end = this.inEl.nativeElement.selectionEnd;

    this.form.reset(....)

    this.inEl.nativeElement.setSelectionRange(start, end);
 }
```

you can implement your own ControlValueAccessor with writeValue method that will keep the selection.